# Socket Receive exception

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

Below is my code :

```
Method()
{
 IPEndPoint _remoteEndpoint = GetRemoteEndPoint(TargetIp);
  byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[65536];
 
 var sourceEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(hostIP), 5003);
 Socket socket = new Socket(sourceEndpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
 socket.Bind(sourceEndpoint);
 string message = "Some message";
 dataBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
 socket.SendTo(dataBuffer, _remoteEndpoint);
 socket.ReceiveTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(30000);

 //Recieve
 IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(TargetIp), 5002);
 int receivedDataLength = socket.Receive(dataBuffer, SocketFlags.None);
}


  public IPEndPoint GetRemoteEndPoint(string targetIp)
  {
    var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Udp);
    socket.Connect(targetIp, 5002);
    IPEndPoint remoteEndpoint = socket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
    socket.Close();
    return remoteEndpoint;
  }
```

I get below excpetion for the line "int receivedDataLength = socket.Receive(dataBuffer, SocketFlags.None);"

"A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer
or some other network limit,
or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself"

Thanks

Changed the buffer size and also tried to read less buffer size on Receive(). but did not worked

Comment: After the line `dataBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);` the buffer will only be 12 bytes long (the length of "Some message") which is probably too short for the received message

Comment: How did you change the buffer size and how did you read less buffer size? Please add updated code to your question.

Comment: Hi Shingo,  I tried to to change the buffer size by byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];. I tried to read less buffer by socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveBuffer, 1024); - maybe this is not correct

Comment: Hi Klaus Gutter, Thanks for the reply. But how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Klaus Gutter, how can I make Receive() to accept short messages ?

Comment: You can just do `dataBuffer = new byte[4096];` Side note: I really don't understand the point of the lines `IPEndPoint _remoteEndpoint = GetRemoteEndPoint(TargetIp);` and the second `IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(TargetIp), 5002);` they are unnecessary

Comment: Hi  Charlieface, Thanks for the reply, but dataBuffer = new byte[4096]; did not fix this issue. 'IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(TargetIp), 5002)' - I can remove this redundant code.

Comment: It worked after changing the code to ' ReceiveMessageFrom' :          IPPacketInformation ipPacketInformation;
                EndPoint remote = (EndPoint)remoteEndpoint;
                SocketFlags socketFlags = SocketFlags.None;
                int receivedDataLength = socket.ReceiveMessageFrom(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length, ref socketFlags, ref remote, out ipPacketInformation);

Comment: But using ReceiveMessageFrom(), I could get only part of message, not complete message

Comment: I think now it is working after creating new buffer for receiver as below :                                                                                     byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[4096];  int receivedDataLength = socket.Receive(receiveBuffer, SocketFlags.None);